# Capitalizing hyphenated names

Tags: java

I am using `WordUtils` from apache commons to properly normalize people's names. For example,

```
AnGEl lEe -> Angel Lee
```

And it works great. Now one of the test cases I've come up with is hyphenated names. Typically, each part of the hyphen(s) have the first letter capitalized, so I expect

```
AnGeL lEe-YaNG --> Angel Lee-Yang
```

However, using my existing method that simply calls `capitalizeFully` results in

```
Angel Lee-yang
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Use a different utility function and/or write your own? Perhaps recognize strings that contain hyphens and break them up, capitalizing what's after the hyphen separately?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass multiple delimiters to the overloaded [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully(String, char...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String,%20char...%29) method:

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("AnGeL lEe-YaNG", ' ', '-')
```

Comment: Oh, I was wondering whether the intellisense was just showing `...` in the signature because it was to long or something. I was making separate calls but didn't think of just passing all my delimiters in!

Comment: @MxyL That is called `vararg`.

Answer (score 4):

So this seems to actually be a known issue in Apache's `WordUtils` method `WordUtils.capitalizeFully` before `WordUtils` version 2.1. 
If you're still interested in using `WordUtils` use the following:

```
`WordUtils.capitalizeFully("JEfF SamPsOn-bROWN", new char[]{' ', '-'});
```

What this will do is it will capitalize everything after the delimters in the character array. This basically will capitalize only the J, S and B.

For more info you can check out:
[Word Utils Documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html

There's capitalizeFully(String str, char[] delimiters) which can solve your problem. Can you use this method or you don't have access to the code that calls capitalizeFully?

Answer (score 1):

Use the overload of capitalizeFully that takes a set of delimiters, and pass in '-' as one of them :

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("i aM.fine", {'.'}) = "I am.Fine"
```

[WordUtils reference](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String,%20char...%29)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you also include other chars like ', ` and -, —, ...:

```
org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils.capitalizeFully(name.trim(), ' ', '-', '—', '\'', '`')
```

This handles the following almost real world example :)

`mel colm-cille gerard o'brian` -> `Mel Colm-Cille Gerard O'Brian`

- https://www.denverpost.com/2008/02/21/apostrophe-in-your-name-can-cause-a-world-otrouble/
- [What are all of the allowable characters for people's names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421046/what-are-all-of-the-allowable-characters-for-peoples-names)
- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

BONUS: In addition to trim also consider removing duplicate whitespace.

NOTE: Maybe handle this in the UI instead of doing this too early ...