# Using RegEx for validating First and Last names in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation, match, names

I am trying to validate a `String` which contains the first & last name of a person. The acceptable formats of the names are as follows.

```
Bruce Schneier                  
Schneier, Bruce
Schneier, Bruce Wayne
O’Malley, John F.
John O’Malley-Smith
Cher
```

I came up with the following program that will validate the String variable. The `validateName` function should return `true` if the name format matches any of the mentioned formats able. Else it should return `false`.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class telephone {

    public static boolean validateName (String txt){
        String regx = "^[\\\\p{L} .'-]+$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
        return matcher.find();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String name = "Ron O’’Henry";

        System.out.println(validateName(name));

    }
}
```

But for some reason, it is returning `false` for any value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens with `John Von Neumann`? How about `Eddie Van Halen`? `Hans Ten Brink`?  `Arturo Dell'Antonio`?  I spent seven years working for a publishing company and hundreds of hours working on this problem.  Answer: There is no algorithm that can do this 100%, and you need to build and maintain a list of surname prefixes.  It's a ***hard*** problem.

Comment: The issue with your regex is the four backslashes.. when you only need 2, but that doesn't make your regex actually match all the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[\p{L}\s.’\-,]+$
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/dQ8fK8/1

### Explanation:

1. The **biggest** problem you have is `'` and `’` is different. You can only achieve that character by copy pasting from the text.
2. Use `\-` instead of `-` in `[]` since it will be mistaken as a range. For example: `[a-z]`
3. You can use `\s` instead of  for matching any whitespaces.

Comment: `-` is valid unescaped in a character class (`[]`) as long as it is either *first* or *last*, which it is, so it's good.

Comment: And the **biggest** problem was actually having too many backslashes.

Comment: Well, that's true. I just didn't point it out. I think he'll get it by seeing my code

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
^[^\s]+,?(\s[^\s]+)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You put too many backslashes in the regex: `"^[\\\\p{L} .'-]+$"`
After Java literal interpretation, that is: `^[\\p{L} .'-]+$`
Which means match any combination of the following characters:

```
\  p  {  L  }  space  .  '  -
```

If you change to: `"^[\\p{L} .'-]+$"`
Regex will see: `^[\p{L} .'-]+$`
Which means match any combination of the following characters:

```
letters  space  .  '  -
```

---

BUT: **Don't validate names**.

See [What are all of the allowable characters for people's names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/421046/5221149), which leads to [Personal names around the world](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names).

In short: *You can't, so don't*.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. That little snippet was only part of a classroom stuff. But I'll definitely keep your suggestions in mind when I'm working with real world projects.