# @Pattern(regex = "" ) Spring validator

Tags: regex, spring-validator

I want to validate a name for instance.
A name must be composed of words separated by " " or "-".
Example: "Jean-Luc Melenchon", "Xavi Hernandez"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to be working fine

```
[A-Za-zàâéêèìôùûçÀÂÉÊÈÌÔÙÛÇ']+(\\s|\\-[A-Z]+)*
```

Comment: Really? How Does it treat this name?
`Breandán Dalton`
Or this one?
Влади́мир Ильи́ч Улья́нов

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirements correctly, you want a name validator whose rule is to make sure *each name contains atleast one space or one hyphen (-)*. You could use this regex:

```
^.*(\s|-)+.*$
```

- `(\s|-)+` means there should be atleast one space (`\s`) or hyphen (`-`)
- `.*` allows any number of characters before and after the space

Will match successfully with

```
Jean-Luc Melenchon
Xavi Hernandez
Lionel Messi
Zlatan Ibrahimovic
```

Will not match with below (because they don't have a space or a hyphen)

```
Deco
Rivaldo
Kaka
O'Shea
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a lab exercise, knock yourself out. If it's going to be used in a real-life application, do not think you know what a valid name is.

Take a look at 
[Using RegEx for validating First and Last names in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831572/using-regex-for-validating-first-and-last-names-in-java?rq=1)
and 
[PHP Regex for human names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261338/php-regex-for-human-names)

As Pascal Martin says in the latter,

> one day or another, your code will meet a name that it thinks is "wrong"... And how do you think one would react when an application tells him "your name is not valid" ?