# How to allow user to input alphabets with space for name( e.g. John Mike) but disallow user to input alphabets with digits value?

Tags: c, programming-languages

I want to create a simple **C program** to allow user to key in their name and print out their name(e.g. John Mike). But i also want the program to disallow the user to key in name with digits value within the name(e.g. John34 Mike).

I know how to use `scanf("%[^\n]",&name);` but with that user can **accidentally** enter digits into input name.
I want to disallow user to input alphabets with digits value.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: There is no way in standard C to filter the input key-for-key, so if you want to do that you need to use some platform-specific code (possibly wrapped in some library). You can check after the input is done, but not stop the digits from being entered.

Comment: Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

> How to allow user to input alphabets with space for name( e.g. John Mike) but disallow user to input alphabets with digits value?

Read in the entire *line* of input into a *string* and then process the string.

---

Assess the string for legitimate characters and patterns.

Important to be generous in what is valid and consider various culture issues.  Name validity testing is a sensitive issue.  Easy to get [negative feed](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/218174/51392) attempting to discuss it. Also may be considered [not constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/421046/2410359).

Use `isalpha()` for first level check and then check for other valid characters insuring at least one alpha.

`isalpha()` is [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_localization_functions) sensitive and offers *some* level of internationalization.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool name_test1(const char *s) {
  const char *between_char = "-'";  // Allow O'Doul, Flo-Jo.  Adjust as needed
  bool valid = false;
  while (*s) {
    if (isalpha((unsigned char ) *s)) {
      valid = true;
    } else if (*s == ' ' && valid) { // or  isspace((unsigned char) *s) for any white-space
      valid = false; // valid char must follow
    } else if (strchr(between_char, *s) != NULL && valid) {
      valid = false; // valid char must follow
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    s++;
  }
  return valid;
}
```

The `&& valid` in `*s == ' ' && valid` insures a leading space is not valid.

Example:

```
void ntest(const char *s) {
  printf("%d <%s>\n", name_test1(s), s);
}

int main(void) {
  ntest("John Mike");
  ntest("John34 Mike");
  ntest("John Mike ");
  ntest(" John Mike");
  ntest("Flo-Jo");
  ntest("O'Doul");

  char name[100];
  while (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)) {
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';  // lop off potential trailing \n
    if (name_test1(name)) puts("Acceptable name");
    else puts("Unacceptable name");
  }
}

1 <John Mike>
0 <John34 Mike>
0 <John Mike >
0 < John Mike>
1 <Flo-Jo>
1 <O'Doul>
...
```

---

Best to **not** use `scanf("%[^\n]",&name);` it has problems: It reads *almost* a line, the `'\n'` is not read.  A line of only `"\n"` is a problem.  It has no protection against over running the buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Get the input using [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function. And then check the string by using [isdigit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm) function to allow or disallow the input string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
       {
           FILE *stream;
           char *line = NULL;
           size_t len = 80;
           ssize_t nread;



           nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin);
           printf("Retrieved line %s", line);
       for(int i=0;line[i]!='\0';i++)
        if(isdigit(line[i])){
            printf("Disallow\n");
                return 0;}
       printf("Allow\n");
       return 0;    

       }
```